# SQL DATIME convert issue

Tags: sql

I have a column that displays data in the following format:

```
2017-10-11T14:00:56.000+0200
```

I want to display the date in this desired format:

```
2018-07-31 13:11:11
```

The column in the base table is of type `NVARCHAR`.

Please help

Comment: What type of DB?

Comment: You should first fix your borken data model. **Never**, ever store date/time values in `varchar` columns

Comment: Don't confuse people, have sample data and expected result that match each other.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try something like this:

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(charDt, '%Y-%m-%d %h:%i:%s'), charDt
FROM (
    SELECT '2017-10-11T14:00:56.000+0200' AS charDt
) z
```

but horse is right about not storing datetimes as strings.  That's why there's a datetime format.  And you should also include at least the kind of database you are using and ideally sample data.